# How to run Django APScheduler on a view function

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I want to run a Django view every day preferably at a specific time that calls an API and saves the data in a ForeignKey relational model. I can't use the schedule package in python because it requires infinite loop which can't run alongside a web server. Django APScheduler looks like an elegant solution though the problem is view functions take request as an argument which can't be passed to APScheduler which I need to save the data with the user's id thus I'm getting a Name error

views.py

```
def sync_data():

  api_url = ""

  access_token = RefreshToken.response

  headers = {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token),
     'Content-Type': 'application/json;encoding=utf-8',
  }

  user_id = request.user.id 
  
  response = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
  
  r = response.json()
  

  s = Model(user=request.user, starttime = startdate , endtime = endate, field = i['value'][0])
  s.save()

 return redirect('app:dash')
```

scheduler.py

```
from .views import sync_data

def start():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_jobstore(DjangoJobStore(), "default")
    # run this job every 24 hours
    scheduler.add_job(sync_data, 'interval', hours=24, name='sync_daily_data', jobstore='default')
    register_events(scheduler)
    scheduler.start()
    print("Scheduler started...", file=sys.stdout)
```

How do I go about this? Appreciate any help I'll get

Comment: So rewrite function that does not require user.id or it takes user id/ids from database

Answer (score -1):

You can use Django-Celery package. Doc [Here](https://github.com/celery/django-celery)